# Mac OS X shutdown always fails after iTunes was started once

Tags: macos, itunes

I have some mystery on my both MacBooks (Air & Pro):

If I used iTunes at least one time during the uptime, the system never shuts down, it just hangs on a blue screen with the spinner rotating forever. If I don't run iTunes, everything is perfect.

The magic is that both MacBooks have different OS: Lion & Snow Leopard, different software installed. The only thing that was migrated from Snow Leopard to Lion is iTunes and my user account.

But creating different user and complete iTunes removal & reinstalling doesn't help.

`system.log` & `launchd-shutdown.log` seem ok, killing iTunesHelper process before shutdown doesn't help either.

Comment: Is there any "secret" place or log for iTunes or shutdown processes to look in?

Comment: Aristofun, sorry, I'm having trouble following your question, can you please provide as much detail as you can on each step that you have taken? Also, what version number of iTunes were you using on snow leopard, and which version are you now using on Lion? Which parts of iTunes are you exporting/importing, is it just your music library? Was this broken on snowleopard first, and *then* you tried to get it to work on Lion? Apologies if I am misinterpreting your question..

Comment: It began on Snow Leo (macbook pro early 2011) i don't know wich itunes version. 
Then I made TimeMachine backup of everything except my ~/Music folder and restored it on my new MacBook Air Lion machine.

Comment: Then everything on macbook air was updated (iTunes became 10.6.1, OS 10.7.4)

Comment: After I found the reason of the problem I reinstalled iTunes on both machines to the latest 10.6.1 – still have problem even though both macbooks have different iTunes libraries.
It is only Time Machine backup that i moved from one macbook to another.

Comment: SO i suppose it's some file or files related to iTunes that stuck at some of my user folders. But don't understand how to locate that specific case.

Comment: Ok thanks - is it possible that when you restored your user data on lion, there were some *other* random of files mixed up (a tv show or movie) and that iTunes was open when you restored your data.. i have a feeling that this corrupts iTunes and might be causing your problem..

Comment: mmm... i had blank macbook&itunes when i restored my backup, and also i tried to completely cleanup iTunes & all its preferences&libraries.  The only reasonable explanation i see is some files in some system folders that iTunes indirectly depends on. Files that was migrated with TimeMachine.

Comment: Problem still exist, can't find anything new about this issue :(

Answer (score 0):

If you use Kaspersky Security for Mac, try uninstalling it using the uninstaller that comes on the installation media.

Even if you don't use it, try running the uninstaller anyway, as you may have installed the trial once upon a time and still have a kernel extension kicking around without realizing it.

You can check this by starting Terminal.app, and running this:

```
kextstat -kl | awk ' !/apple/ { print $6 } '
```

This will print out non-Apple kernel extensions you have installed. If you see Kaspersky in the list it returns, this is probably the cause, and you will need to run the uninstaller.

*Source (and some more great suggestions): http://detechdev.com/blog/troubleshooting-mac-os-x-hang-on-shutdown*

---

I've struggled with this exact issue for months, and your post inspired me to keep going. This solved the issue for me. (Thank you!)

Comment: In case it's not Kaspersky for you, though, here are some of the other things I tried: (1) start iTune after booting in Safe Mode; (2) compare system.log in Console.app for failed vs. successful restarts; (3) Uninstall Parallels Desktop, AirFoil Instant On; (4) create an empty iTunes library; (5) disable wireless networking (which disables automatic updates, iTunes Match, Genius, album artwork downloads, AirPlay, etc.)   Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

The problem should be solved when using Time Machine off.

Comment: Could you provide some additional information why that helps?